# How to get deviceready event in Cordova/ionic?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building an app using the [ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/) (which is built on top of [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)) and I now want to catch the deviceready event. Around the internet I've found various methods of doing this. I've tried the following three ways:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {console.log('IT IS READY!');});

$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {console.log('IT IS READY!');});

window.ionic.Platform.ready(function() {console.log('IT IS READY!');});
```

but none of these work. I surrounded these lines with log statements, and all code before AND after it is executed, so it doesn't halt there. I'm trying this on a physical Android device (haven't tried iOS yet).

I don't get any error messages. The only possibly relevant log I get in my terminal is one referring to the keyboard which cannot be read:

```
I/chromium(25678): [INFO:CONSOLE(20)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Keyboard' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js (20)
```

Does anybody know why this doesn't work and how I can solve it? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The default 'blank' Ionic template has this code in `app.js` and it works perfectly.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

  });
})
```

Maybe you are placing your `$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {});` in the wrong place.